# default child div to open onClick

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've modified showonlyone div toggle to make it show a div when a link is click
the issue is that it only works on 1 div even though the IDs (#origin)are similar. I don't understand how it wouldn't work for the other divs.

```
    function showonlyone(thechosenone)
 {
     $('#origin').css('display','block');
     $('.mcont').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).fadeIn(800);
          }
          else {
               $(this).fadeOut(200);
          }
     });
}
```

[LINK: Actual website in development](http://stipz.50webs.com)

Character 1 > Origin Div would be shown  -- 
that works properly but the other 3 doesn't display the div 
and you have to click it first and it also remembers which div is open when to my understand should have been overridden by the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you call `showmini('origin');` after FadeIn?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Class ...ID must be unique always**

*Do like this ,, asign class*
 *For Example:*    **$('.origin')**

```
 function showonlyone(thechosenone)
 {
     $('.origin').css('display','block');
     $('.mcont').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).fadeIn(800);
          }
          else {
               $(this).fadeOut(200);
          }
     });
}
```

Comment: I couldn't use class attribute anymore since it's a part of a class/set.
Thank you for the tip, I didn't realize I was only assigning it to one div only if I used ID